# how to specify zone for aws in pkgcloud while createClient?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, libcloud, pkgcloud

I'm using pkgcloud npm for multicloud access. and i want to list out all instances from all zone (like US East (N. Virginia),US West (Oregon),US West (N. California),EU (Ireland)) etc.

here is my code

```
var aws = require('pkgcloud').compute.createClient({
provider : 'amazon',
key:'Secret Access Key',
keyId:'Access Key ID'
});
```

one more thing i need to ask you is can i use pkgcloud in production ?  I've also read apache libcloud so which is better to use for production ? pkgcloud or libcloud ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in `zone` information in the options

```
client.createServer({
  zone: 'us-west-2'
  // etc..
}, function (er, svr) {
  // code...
});
```

The AWS options aren't perfectly documented, but they are pretty easy to find in the source code: https://github.com/pkgcloud/pkgcloud/blob/master/lib/pkgcloud/amazon/compute/client/servers.js#L117-L201

Comment: I'm curious why we have region as part of the client options, but zone as a server option. Feels like that's a bit inconsistent.

Comment: hii, i already tried that, its not working :( , see here is code 

var aws = require('pkgcloud').compute.createClient({
 zone: 'EC2_EU',
 provider : 'amazon',
 key:'',
 keyId:''
});

but its always list instances from US_EAST, even i tried zone: 'EU', but still same prb.  like passing zone doesn't make sense.

same if i pass in apache libcloud its work properly. its displayed instances running in EC2_EU.

Comment: That is not a valid zone name. See here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ec2_region

Comment: @indexzero i've tried zone: 'Z1BKCTXD74EZPE' and zone:'eu-west-1' but still it display instances from US_EAST, i've running instances from EU (Ireland) Region but i can't display using pkgcloud.  oky here is my code var aws = require('pkgcloud').compute.createClient({
 zone:'Z1BKCTXD74EZPE',
 provider:'amazon',
 key:'',
 keyId:''
});

Comment: @indexzero i'm using "version": "0.9.4",